# localStorage getItem undefined

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm having some trouble retrieving values from localStorage. I'm trying to store inputs and selects from a form and use it on another page after clicking on submit. This is what the form looks like :

```html
<form action="thank-you.html" role="form" id="form" data-toggle="validator" method="get" onsubmit="callme()">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputSurfaceDuTerrain">Surface du terrain (Optionnel)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputSurfaceDuTerrain" name="inputSurfaceDuTerrain"
        placeholder="Ex. 500" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text">m²</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my JS for this file :

```
function callme() {
    let inputSurfaceDuTerrain = document.getElementById('inputSurfaceDuTerrain');
    localStorage.setItem('inputSurfaceDuTerrain', inputSurfaceDuTerrain.value);
};
```

On my other file, the thank-you.html page, i'd like to print the input value on screen. Here are my html & JS :

```html
<p id="inputSurfaceDuTerrain"></p>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('inputSurfaceDuTerrain').innerText = "inputSurfaceDuTerrain, " + localStorage.getItem('inputSurfaceDuTerrain');
    };
</script>
```

But it prints "undefined" on screen...

Comment: Is it getting saved to local storage correctly?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Try replacing `onsubmit="callme()"` with `onsubmit="callme(); return false;"` and see?

Comment: It gets passed in the url (http://localhost:3000/formulaire/thank-you.html?inputSurfaceDuTerrain=500) but if i `console.log(localStorage)` it is empty, and it prints null on the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is submitting which goes to a new page - therefore, you have to manually set the URL.

Change your form to this:

```
<form role="form" id="form" data-toggle="validator">
```

And add this JavaScript on the page where it's located:

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", callme);
function callme(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let inputSurfaceDuTerrain = document.getElementById('inputSurfaceDuTerrain');
    localStorage.setItem('inputSurfaceDuTerrain', inputSurfaceDuTerrain.value);
    window.location.href = "thank-you.html";
};
```

Now it should work.